# Is there a way to make a progess bar which is incremented each time an array row is read?

Tags: reactjs, xlsx, xls

In my use case, the user upload an excel file which is read in my react app with "read-excel-file". This library allows me to put the excel data in an array. Once the excel data are in my array, I read every row to do a test on them. What I want, is to display a progress bar which is incremented each time one line is processed.

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
...
xlsx.map((row, index) => {
        makeTheBusiness(row);
        setProgress(index);
})
```

Unfortunately the progress variable is not set after each row and stay as "0".

If somebody have an idea, it will be great !
Thanks

Comment: you can start by trying ```setProgress(progress + index);```

Comment: try this ```setProgress(prev => prev + index)```

Comment: *Progress variable is set at the end (once the map is done).

Comment: @VersifiXion not working ;(

Comment: @mirik999 not working ;(

Comment: can you add a ```console.log(Math.ceil(progress += ((100 / xlsx.length))))``` just below the ```makeThebusiness(row)``` and tell me what do you see in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)

xlsx.map((row, index) => {
        makeTheBusiness(row);
        onProgress(index);
})


const onProgress = useCallback((index) => {
  console.log('index =>', index)
  setProgress(index)
}, [progress])
```

Comment: Not working, always the same issue... I console.logged progress variable after setProgress and value stay as 0